# what has to be done to run a ejb service in jboss from a client in tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, ejb, tomcat6

I am using 2 JBOSS ejb services in my project that runs in Tomcat. When I am running my project, an exception occurs,

```
Caused by:java.rmi.MarshalException: Failed to communicate.  Problem during marshalling/unmarshalling; nested exception is: 
    java.io.OptionalDataException
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.transport(SocketClientInvoker.java:306)
    at org.jboss.remoting.RemoteClientInvoker.invoke(RemoteClientInvoker.java:143)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:525)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:488)
    at org.jboss.invocation.unified.interfaces.UnifiedInvokerProxy.invoke(UnifiedInvokerProxy.java:184)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeInvoker(InvokerInterceptor.java:365)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invoke(InvokerInterceptor.java:197)
    at org.jboss.proxy.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.HomeInterceptor.invoke(HomeInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.create(Unknown Source)
.....
```

Please tell me why these happens.what has to be done to run a ejb service in jboss from a client in tomcat?

Comment: Check your libraries may be u don"t have the same version in the client and server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reason for `java.rmi.MarshalException` may be because the local class and the remote class are of different versions. Because of this conflict during marshall/unmarshall the receiver does not accept the protocol version  of the invoker.

I would recommend you to recompile all your local/remote classes. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I did it and Still I am getting the same exception.